# How to set connection timeout

Tags: c++, https

I'm looking at the c++ code below that sets an http connection and opens a request (or so I believe), and would like to increase the connection timeout value, so that I can send bigger files. I understand that this isn't the best solution to handle big files, but I feel that it is the quickest one and right now time is a deal-breaker.

Edit : I'm running on .NET framework 3.5

Anyone to the rescue?

```
connection = session.GetHttpConnection (server,
                                        INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID,
                                        INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT);
pHTTP = connection->OpenRequest (CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST,
                                 path, 
                                 NULL, 
                                 1, 
                                 NULL, 
                                 NULL, 
                                 INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID);
```

Comment: What framework are you using to make the request?

Comment: Hi, just edited the question. Its .net 3.5

Comment: Yes but what in .net? What is "session"?

Comment: @ChristianStewart, where can i check that?

Comment: The default TCP connection timeout cannot be increased, and it has nothing to do with sending bigger files.

Comment: @EJP - So when someone doesn't really understand something, and asks about it, they should be penalized ? Why the -1 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not test this myself, but there looks to be an easy answer

Look art M$ reference material here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114(v=vs.85).aspx

The code could be sth like this:

b = InternetSetOption(hInternetHandle, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, 
&dwTimeut, sizeof(DWORD));

Comment: I ended up with : `/*defines the connection timeout in ms*/ DWORD dwTimeout = 1200000;InternetSetOption(*pHTTP,INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, &dwTimeout, sizeof(DWORD));`  `